# Issues on styling multilist row separately codename one

Tags: java, codenameone

In [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com)'s `MultiList` class I can customize individual elements with styles such as `MultiLine1` etc. However, I'd like to have a more powerful way of styling thru color coding individual elements. E.g. I'd like one line to be green and another to be yellow and base it on application business logic.

However, due to the opaque nature of the `MultiList` API its harder to customize.

update:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    Hashtable hm = (Hashtable) fetchresponses.get(i);
    String detailsHome = (String) hm.get("details");
    newsIdValue = (String) hm.get("news_id");
    HashMap <String, Object> m = new HashMap <String, Object> ();
    m.put("Line1", detailsHome);
    m.put("Line1_uiid", "red");
    m.put("newsIdHome", newsIdValue);
    m.put("newsIdHome_uiid", "blue");
    // m.put("MultiButton_uiid","red"); //does nothing
    // i want this row containing detailsHome & newsIdValue to be of diff. bg
    newsHome.add(m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`MultiList` is designed to be simple to use but not as dynamic as just building your own list with your own renderer. I would further recommend avoiding lists altogether and using `Component`/`Container` or Infinite Scroll for anything under 10,000 rows. In those cases this problem wouldn't exist at all.

We describe doing this here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/json-overscroll-more.html

> With MultiList/GenenricListCellRenderer one of the common issues is
>   making a UI where a specific component within the list renderer has a
>   different UIID style. E.g. this can be helpful to mark a label within
>   the list as red, for instance in cases of a list of monetary
>   transactions. Up until now the only answer we had was: you need to
>   create your own renderer. With the latest version of
>   GenericListCellRenderer (MultiList uses GenericListCellRenderer
>   internally) we have another option.
>
> Normally to build the model for a renderer of this type we use
>   something like:

```
map.put("componentName", "Component Value");
```

> What if we want componentName to be red? Just use:
>   map.put("componentName_uiid", "red");
>
> This will apply the uiid "red" to the component which you can then
>   style in the them. Notice that once you start doing this you need to
>   define this entry for all entries e.g.:

```
map.put("componentName_uiid", "blue");
```

> Otherwise the component will stay red for the next entry (since
>   renderer acts like a rubber stamp ).

To do this for the parent component which is unnamed by default in the MultiList do something like this:

```
list.getSelectedButton().setName("RenderMB");
list.getUnselectedButton().setName("RenderMB");
```

You can then determine the style of the background using `RenderMB_uiid`.

Comment: when i used map.put("componentName_uiid", "red"); it applies in only one component which i can customize using gui builder too, but i have componentName2 in the same row as well that i did map.put("componentName2_uiid,"blue"); it makes one item red and other blue but i want to change the bg of its row too. eg row1 green, row2 grey etc. One more thing i set component value red, it works but other than red like green, blue etc doesnt work. Is there a bug?

Comment: Did you try defining `MultiButton_uiid`?

Comment: MultiButton_uiid did nothing at all... i have updated what i did above. plz hav a look.

Comment: I revised my answer to include this